# Ionic config.xml different widget id for different platforms

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ionic-framework, ionic2

We use

```
   <widget id="com.activityo" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

for android and need to change widget id for ios.
I mean i want to use 2 different widget id for different platforms.

Is there anyway ?? thanks

Comment: were you able to find the answer to this?

Comment: @Ced I posted an answer for the same. Check it out below.

Answer (score 5):

The way you do it is like this:

```
<widget android-packageName="androidappid" id="defaultappid" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="iosappid" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would use in the **config.xml** file:

```
<widget id="com.mywebsite.myapp" 
        android-packageName="com.mywebsite.myandroid" 
        ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.mywebsite.myios" 
        version="1.0.0" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

In the above code:

`id` - **Required** - Specifies the app's reverse-domain identifier.

`android-packageName` - ***Optional*** - Alternative package name for **Android**, overrides id.

`ios-CFBundleIdentifier` - ***Optional*** - Alternative bundle id for **iOS**. Overrides id.

`version` - **Required** - Full version number expressed in major/minor/patch notation.

`xmlns` - **Required** - Namespace for the config.xml document.

`xmlns:cdv` - **Required** - Namespace prefix.

Source: [Cordova Reference for config.xml file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#widget)